# Hex string to bool[] C#

Tags: c#, boolean, hex

I have a hex string `string hex = A5A6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9AAAAAAAAA9552` that I want to convert to a bool array.

I've already found a function that can convert it to a byte array, but I've later discovered that I need a bool array instead. How can I alter this function/create a new one that does the job for me?

```
private byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hexString));
    }

    byte[] data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
    {
        string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
        data[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, feeling a bit lost here!

EDIT:

If I encounter the hex value A5, for example, I'd like to return a bool array consisting of:

```
bool =  {true, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's byte array(byte = 0 - 255) or rather it's bit array(bit = 0 - 1)??

Comment: A byte[] can be interpreted as "bool array" in that you take each bit for a bool value ... then you just need a function that checks a specific bit position and return a bool.

Comment: I don't get your requirement?!? - You are splitting your string into chunks of two, you will there for end up with those 6 unique values `A5`, `A6`, `AA`, `9A`, `95`, `52` - why should `A5` be true? or `52`? and so on? whats your rule for true or false?

Comment: what do you expect the `bool[]` to look like *exactly*? do you have an example input/output? Note that `bool[]` is *incredibly* inefficient, and there may be much better options such as `BitArray`

Comment: Get clear how your boolean is encoded, could be per bit or per byte, or anything in between. The source of your string should be able to tell you.

Comment: I've edited my question, trying to clear up what results I expect!

Comment: @MarcGravell - ping

Comment: @RandRandom - pong

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest level, `BitArray` does everything you need with your existing code:

```cs
var bytes = ConvertHexStringToByteArray("A5");
var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
for(int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(bits[i]);
```

This gets the job done, and doesn't require any re-work, but it isn't a `bool[]`; frankly, I would recommend *against* a `bool[]` - it is a very inefficient way of storing data, but you can use `BitArray` to do that *too*, without needing any extra work:

```cs
var bytes = ConvertHexStringToByteArray("A5");
var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
bool[] arr = new bool[bits.Length];
bits.CopyTo(arr, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
```

You *could* also rework `ConvertHexStringToByteArray` to do the bit math internally, but... it probably isn't a good idea.